# How do I redirect all 404 error url to Subcategory url

Tags: functions, redirect, htaccess, 404-error

I have a b blog of over 200k+ post and I moved all post from a specific category to a subcategory, I have also deleted the post from the my main site, so all the post of that category have been moved to a subcategory.

Our analytics show that a lot of crawling errors, and my wp permalink structure for main site is example.com/postname/, while the one for my sub-category is example.com/stack/postname/

The solution I came up with is to redirect all visits for non-existant URLs of main site to subcategory URLs

Example:

- `mysite.com/postname/` which does not exist will be redirected to my
  sub-category url
- `example.com/stack/postname/` this pages are active and have content.

How would I go about this?

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess . Example shown in that answer.

Comment: That does not fix my issue, because I don't have 404 error page at my public_html, wp theme function would be the best recommendation.

Comment: If you use that link, you can see how to redirect a '404' response to another page. You provide the page you want to show in the command. You don't need a 404 page, you just need the 'errordocument' command to 'catch' a 404 response and send it to the page/link you desire.

Comment: its not working.check my post, I did not mention specific url, I mention urls that match the same url i deleted

Comment: errordocument 404 /your-subcatetory-page-without-domain-name . Place the lines above the WP htaccess lines. Use the actual page you want to redirect to if a page is not found. If you want to do some WP logic to a specific page based on some condition, then create/use a '404' template. Also, see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268669/how-do-i-redirect-all-404-errors-of-a-specific-post-type-to-another-url?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");

header("Location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/subcategory{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"); 

exit();

?>
```

The above code was added directly to themes 404.php and everything worked as expected